# Closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^{k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

Is there a known closed form for the sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}r^{k^2}$?

Comment: After a fashion - though it's usually taken from $k=-\infty$ to $\infty$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Answer (score 3):

$(\theta_3(0,r)+1)/2$ where $\theta_3$ is a Jacobi theta function.